# Leaflet Tutorial Blank Outcome

Tags: html, css, leaflet

I have been trying to understand Leaflet through the first tutorial, and my page keeps coming up blank. Here is the tutorial I was following http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/

Below is the code that I had written with an access token that I generated. I don't understand what is wrong. I have been testing it through GitHub Pages.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
  <title>A Leaflet map!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <style>
    #map{ width 960px; height: 100% }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>
  // initialize the map
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'leafletTestToken1',
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYmxhY2ttb3JlMCIsImEiOiJjaXlub251ZjIwMDJmMnBxems2bmpiYXA2In0.2Hxl5QoDhIY6OR4p3GsU2w'
}).addTo(map);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems. The most significant is that you have not created a map; you've only created a tile layer. You need to create a map to which the tile layer can be added. For example:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
```

Also, the `id` is does not appear to be valid. It needs to correspond to a Mapbox project ID or to one of the pre-defined Mapbox map IDs. For example:

```
id: 'mapbox.streets'
```

And the CSS is not valid; there is a missing `:` after `width`.

There is a working snippet below:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.streets',
  accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYmxhY2ttb3JlMCIsImEiOiJjaXlub251ZjIwMDJmMnBxems2bmpiYXA2In0.2Hxl5QoDhIY6OR4p3GsU2w'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
body { margin: 0 }
#map { width: 100vw; height: 100vh }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought that the map variable was in there at first glance. Thanks to you I am able to get it working. However, I noticed something that I don't understand: if I include the usual < !DOCTYPE html > declaration the page doesn't load. If I remove it from the file it loads just fine. Is this because the declaration isn't needed when the file is already .html?

Comment: In an HTML file, `<!DOCTYPE html>` would be expected, so it shouldn't cause problems. However, in your comment, you have a space between the `<` and the `!DOCTYPE` - that would be a problem.

Comment: Is there an update to this answer? I'm seeing blank screens everywhere, even in the code snippet